# ASP.Net Table display wrong when using master page vs content page

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I adapted JumpyForum to VB.net in master page (ASP.Net). The problem is when I place the html/javascript only in the content page (without master page) everything is displayed correctly [good display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzcoO.jpg); when I use content page with master page the display is completely wrong [wrong display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCzhp.jpg).

This is Forum4 content page WITH master page (master page is the default one)

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site10.Master" CodeBehind="Forum4.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.Forum4" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <STYLE type="text/css">A:link { TEXT-DECORATION: none }
    A:visited { TEXT-DECORATION: none }
    A:active { TEXT-DECORATION: none }
    A:hover { TEXT-DECORATION: underline }
        </STYLE>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (top != self) top.location.href = location.href;
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        onerror = report;
var Selected = 1;


function OnOffPost(e)
{

    if (!e) e = window.event;
  //  var target, evt = e ? e : event;
    // if (evt.srcElement)  target = evt.srcElement;
   // else if (evt.target) target = evt.target;

   var target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;


if (!target) return;

 while (target.id.indexOf('LinkTrigger')<0)
 {

    //alert(target.id + target.id.indexOf('LinkTrigger')+target.parentNode);

     target = target.parentNode;
     if (target.id ==null) return;
     }
  if ( target.id.indexOf('LinkTrigger')<0 )
   return;


   if (Selected)
   {
      var body = document.getElementById(Selected + "ON");
      if (body)
         body.style.display = 'none';
      var head = document.getElementById(Selected + "OFF");
      if (head)
         head.bgColor = '#EDF8F4';
   }

   if (Selected == target.name) // just collapse
      Selected="";
   else
   {
      Selected = target.name;
      var body = document.getElementById(Selected + "ON");
      if (body)
      {
         if (body.style.display=='none')
            body.style.display='';
         else
            body.style.display = 'none';
      }
      var head = document.getElementById(Selected + "OFF");
      if (head)
         head.bgColor = '#B7DFD5';

      if ( body && head && body.style.display != 'none' )
      {
         document.body.scrollTop = FindPosition(head, "Top") - document.body.clientHeight/10;
         OpenMessage(target.name, true);
      }
   }

   if ( e.preventDefault )
      e.preventDefault();
   else
      e.returnValue = false;
   return false;
}

// does its best to make a message visible on-screen (vs. scrolled off somewhere).
function OpenMessage(msgID, bShowTop) {
   var msgHeader = document.getElementById(msgID + "OFF");
   var msgBody = document.getElementById(msgID + "ON");

   // determine scroll position of top and bottom
   var MyBody = document.body;
   var top = FindPosition(msgHeader, 'Top');
   var bottom = FindPosition(msgBody, 'Top') + msgBody.offsetHeight;

   // if not already visible, scroll to make it so
   if ( MyBody.scrollTop > top && !bShowTop)
      MyBody.scrollTop = top - document.body.clientHeight/10;
   if ( MyBody.scrollTop+MyBody.clientHeight < bottom )
      MyBody.scrollTop = bottom-MyBody.clientHeight;
   if ( MyBody.scrollTop > top && bShowTop)
      MyBody.scrollTop = top - document.body.clientHeight/10;
}

// utility
function FindPosition(i,which)
{
   iPos = 0
   while (i!=null)
   {
      iPos += i["offset" + which];
      i = i.offsetParent;
   }
   return iPos
}

function report(message,url,line) {
    alert('Error : ' + message + ' at line ' + line + ' in ' + url);
}

// cause an <B style="COLOR: black; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff66">error</B>:
        </script>
        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr vAlign="top">
                    <td class="ContentPane">
                        <!-- Main Page Contents Start -->
                        <DIV onclick="OnOffPost(event)">
                            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" bgColor="#1d8a0f" border="0">
                                <TBODY>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%">

                                                <table id="ForumTable" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="0" width="100%" bgColor="#1d8a0f" border="0">
                                                    <TBODY>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left">
                                                                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left"><FONT face="Arial" color="#ffffff" size="2"><STRONG><A href="Forum.aspx?id=1"><FONT color="#ffffff">Article 
                                                                                            1</FONT></A> &nbsp;||&nbsp; <A href="Forum.aspx?id=2"><FONT color="#ffffff">Article 
                                                                                            2</FONT></A> ||&nbsp; <A href="Forum.aspx?id=3"><FONT color="#ffffff">Article 3</FONT></A></STRONG></FONT></td>
                                                                        <td align="right"><FONT face="arial" size="2" color="#ffffff">Per page</FONT>&nbsp;
                                                                            <asp:DropDownList id="txtpagesize" runat="server">
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="20" Selected="True">20</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="40">40</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>
                                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                            <asp:Button id="btnsetpaging" runat="server" Text="Set Pagesize"></asp:Button></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr bgColor="#f1f1f1">
                                                            <td><a name="xx0xx"></a>
                                                                <table cellPadding="2" width="100%" bgColor="#b7dfd5" border="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td><IMG height="16" alt="screen" src="images/forum_newmsg.gif" width="16" align="top" border="0">&nbsp;
                                                                            <asp:label id="lblnewmessage" ForeColor="Green" runat="server"></asp:label></td>
                                                                        <td><FONT face="Arial" size="2"></FONT></td>
                                                                        <td noWrap align="right"><font><a href="http://www.codeproject.com"><font face="arial" size="2">Jumpy 
                                                                                        Forum - inspired by Code Project&nbsp;</font> </a></font>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr bgColor="white">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                                                    <TBODY>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td width="100%">
                                                                                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2" bgColor="#f1f1f1" border="0">
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td width="100%"><FONT face="Arial" size="2">Subject&nbsp;</FONT></td>
                                                                                        <td noWrap width="140"><FONT face="Arial" size="2">User&nbsp;</FONT></td>
                                                                                        <td noWrap align="right" width="144"><font><FONT face="Arial" size="2">Date</FONT>&nbsp;</font></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td colSpan="1"><IMG height="5" src="/images/t.gif" width="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <asp:literal id="ltlPost" runat="server"></asp:literal>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td colSpan="1"><IMG height="5" src="/images/t.gif" width="1" border="0" alt="">

                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </TBODY>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr bgColor="#f1f1f1">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <table cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <TD align="left"><asp:label id="lbldate" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Smaller">Label</asp:label></TD>
                                                                        <td vAlign="middle" align="right" width="40%"><FONT face="Arial" size="2"><asp:label id="lblPaging" runat="server">Label</asp:label></FONT></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </TBODY>
                                                </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </TBODY>
                            </table>
                        </DIV>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401" alt="Valid HTML 4.01 Transitional" height="31"
                                width="88" border="0"></a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Content>
```

This is the content page without master page that works perfectly fine:

```
  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Forum3.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.Forum3" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" >
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>JumpyForum </title>
        <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
        <meta content="C#" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
        <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
        <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
        <STYLE type="text/css">A:link { TEXT-DECORATION: none }
    A:visited { TEXT-DECORATION: none }
    A:active { TEXT-DECORATION: none }
    A:hover { TEXT-DECORATION: underline }
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <body style="MARGIN: 0px" text="black" vLink="navy" aLink="red" link="blue" bgColor="white">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if (top != self) top.location.href = location.href;
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        onerror = report;
var Selected = 1;


function OnOffPost(e)
{

    if (!e) e = window.event;
  //  var target, evt = e ? e : event;
    // if (evt.srcElement)  target = evt.srcElement;
   // else if (evt.target) target = evt.target;

   var target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;


if (!target) return;

 while (target.id.indexOf('LinkTrigger')<0)
 {

    //alert(target.id + target.id.indexOf('LinkTrigger')+target.parentNode);

     target = target.parentNode;
     if (target.id ==null) return;
     }
  if ( target.id.indexOf('LinkTrigger')<0 )
   return;


   if (Selected)
   {
      var body = document.getElementById(Selected + "ON");
      if (body)
         body.style.display = 'none';
      var head = document.getElementById(Selected + "OFF");
      if (head)
         head.bgColor = '#EDF8F4';
   }

   if (Selected == target.name) // just collapse
      Selected="";
   else
   {
      Selected = target.name;
      var body = document.getElementById(Selected + "ON");
      if (body)
      {
         if (body.style.display=='none')
            body.style.display='';
         else
            body.style.display = 'none';
      }
      var head = document.getElementById(Selected + "OFF");
      if (head)
         head.bgColor = '#B7DFD5';

      if ( body && head && body.style.display != 'none' )
      {
         document.body.scrollTop = FindPosition(head, "Top") - document.body.clientHeight/10;
         OpenMessage(target.name, true);
      }
   }

   if ( e.preventDefault )
      e.preventDefault();
   else
      e.returnValue = false;
   return false;
}

// does its best to make a message visible on-screen (vs. scrolled off somewhere).
function OpenMessage(msgID, bShowTop) {
   var msgHeader = document.getElementById(msgID + "OFF");
   var msgBody = document.getElementById(msgID + "ON");

   // determine scroll position of top and bottom
   var MyBody = document.body;
   var top = FindPosition(msgHeader, 'Top');
   var bottom = FindPosition(msgBody, 'Top') + msgBody.offsetHeight;

   // if not already visible, scroll to make it so
   if ( MyBody.scrollTop > top && !bShowTop)
      MyBody.scrollTop = top - document.body.clientHeight/10;
   if ( MyBody.scrollTop+MyBody.clientHeight < bottom )
      MyBody.scrollTop = bottom-MyBody.clientHeight;
   if ( MyBody.scrollTop > top && bShowTop)
      MyBody.scrollTop = top - document.body.clientHeight/10;
}

// utility
function FindPosition(i,which)
{
   iPos = 0
   while (i!=null)
   {
      iPos += i["offset" + which];
      i = i.offsetParent;
   }
   return iPos
}

function report(message,url,line) {
    alert('Error : ' + message + ' at line ' + line + ' in ' + url);
}

// cause an <B style="COLOR: black; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff66">error</B>:
        </script>
        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr vAlign="top">
                    <td class="ContentPane">
                        <!-- Main Page Contents Start -->
                        <DIV onclick="OnOffPost(event)">
                            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" bgColor="#1d8a0f" border="0">
                                <TBODY>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="100%">
                                            <form name="myform" id="myform" runat="server">
                                                <table id="ForumTable" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="0" width="100%" bgColor="#1d8a0f" border="0">
                                                    <TBODY>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left">
                                                                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left"><FONT face="Arial" color="#ffffff" size="2"><STRONG><A href="Forum.aspx?id=1"><FONT color="#ffffff">Article 
                                                                                            1</FONT></A> &nbsp;||&nbsp; <A href="Forum.aspx?id=2"><FONT color="#ffffff">Article 
                                                                                            2</FONT></A> ||&nbsp; <A href="Forum.aspx?id=3"><FONT color="#ffffff">Article 3</FONT></A></STRONG></FONT></td>
                                                                        <td align="right"><FONT face="arial" size="2" color="#ffffff">Per page</FONT>&nbsp;
                                                                            <asp:DropDownList id="txtpagesize" runat="server">
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="20" Selected="True">20</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="40">40</asp:ListItem>
                                                                                <asp:ListItem Value="50">50</asp:ListItem>
                                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                            <asp:Button id="btnsetpaging" runat="server" Text="Set Pagesize"></asp:Button></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr bgColor="#f1f1f1">
                                                            <td><a name="xx0xx"></a>
                                                                <table cellPadding="2" width="100%" bgColor="#b7dfd5" border="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td><IMG height="16" alt="screen" src="images/forum_newmsg.gif" width="16" align="top" border="0">&nbsp;
                                                                            <asp:label id="lblnewmessage" ForeColor="Green" runat="server"></asp:label></td>
                                                                        <td><FONT face="Arial" size="2"></FONT></td>
                                                                        <td noWrap align="right"><font><a href="http://www.codeproject.com"><font face="arial" size="2">Jumpy 
                                                                                        Forum - inspired by Code Project&nbsp;</font> </a></font>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr bgColor="white">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                                                    <TBODY>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td width="100%">
                                                                                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2" bgColor="#f1f1f1" border="0">
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td width="100%"><FONT face="Arial" size="2">Subject&nbsp;</FONT></td>
                                                                                        <td noWrap width="140"><FONT face="Arial" size="2">User&nbsp;</FONT></td>
                                                                                        <td noWrap align="right" width="144"><font><FONT face="Arial" size="2">Date</FONT>&nbsp;</font></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td colSpan="1"><IMG height="5" src="/images/t.gif" width="1" border="0" alt=""></td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <asp:literal id="ltlPost" runat="server"></asp:literal>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td colSpan="1"><IMG height="5" src="/images/t.gif" width="1" border="0" alt="">

                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </TBODY>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr bgColor="#f1f1f1">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <table cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <TD align="left"><asp:label id="lbldate" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Smaller">Label</asp:label></TD>
                                                                        <td vAlign="middle" align="right" width="40%"><FONT face="Arial" size="2"><asp:label id="lblPaging" runat="server">Label</asp:label></FONT></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </TBODY>
                                                </table>
                                            </form>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </TBODY>
                            </table>
                        </DIV>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table width='100%'>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <p>
                        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-html401" alt="Valid HTML 4.01 Transitional" height="31"
                                width="88" border="0"></a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Code behind is exactly the same in both cases.